# boot partition on two harddisk mirrror

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning

I have 2 2TB HDDs in my PC. To illustrate it best here is lsblk output

```
sdc                           8:32   0   1.8T  0 disk
├─sdc1                        8:33   0     1G  0 part  /boot
└─sdc2                        8:34   0   1.8T  0 part
  └─md126                     9:126  0   1.8T  0 raid1
    ├─lvm_data-root         253:0    0    61G  0 lvm   /
    └─lvm_data-home         253:2    0   1.8T  0 lvm   /home
sdd                           8:48   0   1.8T  0 disk
├─sdd1                        8:49   0     1G  0 part
└─sdd2                        8:50   0   1.8T  0 part
  └─md126                     9:126  0   1.8T  0 raid1
    ├─lvm_data-root         253:0    0    61G  0 lvm   /
    └─lvm_data-home         253:2    0   1.8T  0 lvm   /home
```

`sdd` is identical copy of `sda`. If `sdd` fails I can replace it, but if `sda` fails I lose `/boot` partition.

Is there any way to make it more *redundant*? So `sdd1` is always a mirror copy of `sda1`

I'm not sure, but is it possible to mount 2 partitions to `/boot` so those are replicated?

Comment: Are you using UEFI mode or BIOS mode boot? Are you using GRUB or a different bootloader?

Comment: It's a centos 7 default install, and I don't know if its UEFI atm... I'm almost sure it's not a UEFI (it's a server motherboard).

Comment: I usually put boot on a md RAID1 (md superblock at end) - works fine with BIOS and 99% of UEFI.